# How do you enter a hammock?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, differences

For this morning's debate with my children on the way to school, we discussed what was the appropriate verb for entering a hammock; in vs on.

Ultimately, the conclusion was that it depended on the style of hammock. The taut flat ones, you get on those. The more cocoon type ones, you get in those.

I was curious if we could get a ruling on whether we're right or not.

Comment: Aren't the cocoons _hammock-tents_?

Comment: The original Mayan _hamaca_ is made of knotted string, and you definitely get in it. The flat ones are just swinging cots, and you get on those. So you and your kids got the right answer. Good for you!

Comment: You *plop* into it.

Comment: @HotLicks Can always depend on you to zero in on the main issue.

Comment: @Barmar - At least I'm not being negative!